# Set up a Service principle to a AAD group by Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, azure, automation, azure-active-directory

I need a Help to solve it by bash Scripting .
Have a look a condition for Script :

I have a bash Script where i put the group id & list of Service Principle to that group & it works fine & ok but i want to modify that Script to like below:

1. Script want to ask me what group you to insert here > " Put in the Group Id or Name"
2. Script want to ask me what Service Principle you to insert to that group  > "Put the Service Principle name or ID"
3. Paste my Whole below :

groupId="ff9cf2bd-38d5-49ab-af7a-3ac4f7fba81a"
sp_list=("emran-test-demo-03" "emran-test-demo-04" "TurbonomicSP")

for sp_name in "${sp_list[@]}"
do
spObjId=$(az ad sp list --display-name "$sp_name" --query '[0].id' --output tsv)

```
if [ -n "$spObjId" ]; then
    az ad group member add --group $groupId --member-id $spObjId
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) added to AAD Group successfully."
    else
        echo "Failed to add Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) to AAD Group."
    fi
else
    echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name not found."
fi
```

done

Please someone come to help me .

Emmi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To prompt the script for the user input, modify the script like below:**

```bash
# Prompt for the Group ID
read -p "Enter the Group ID or Name: " groupId

# Prompt for the Service Principals
read -p "Enter the Service Principals (separated by spaces): " -a sp_list

for sp_name in "${sp_list[@]}"; do
    spObjId=$(az ad sp list --display-name "$sp_name" --query '[0].id' --output tsv)

    if [ -n "$spObjId" ]; then
        az ad group member add --group $groupId --member-id $spObjId
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) added to AAD Group successfully."
        else
            echo "Failed to add Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) to AAD Group."
        fi
    else
        echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name not found."
    fi
done
```

[image]

***The Service Principals added successfully to the group like below:***

[image]

Comment: Can you look my another Ticket regarding Bash Script @Rukmini https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77271706/how-to-create-a-user-managed-identity-assign-to-key-vault-service-bus-by-bas

Comment: I am really in Bash so need a help plz . I always work with PS . Thanks for quick reply